# Is there a "natural" example of a total, computable but non-primitive recursive function?

Tags: computability

Every example of a total, computable but non-primitive recursive function seems to be explicitly constructed for proof theory, or in Godelian proofs of "what is the name of this book?" kind. But is there a non-primitive recursive function or algorithm that occurs naturally, like in physics or number theory or even in industry software?

Comment: The standard example is the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). My (possibly incorrect) understanding is that it was "contrived" for this purpose. However, its occurrence in other contexts such as in the asymptotic complexity of [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) and its relationship to things like arrow notations suggests that it is somewhat "natural" despite its origins.

Comment: I don't know if you call it natural or not, but you can always just compute $R(x) = P_x(x) + 1$ where $P$ is an enumeration of your computing model, for any computing model with only total machines.  By that definition, $\forall y ~:~ R \ne P_y$.  Maybe that is what you mean by Godelian though.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29519/what-functions-can-system-f-not-compute) gives us a hint, namely that an interpreter for a language more powerful than primitive recursion, is itself not primitive recursive. For example, System F has no self-interpreter, and thus any interpreter for System F is not self-recursive.

This then extends to Turing-complete languages: JavaScript, Python, Ruby, etc. Any interpreter you run is utilizing functions more powerful than primitive recursion.